# Modulation that is used in WiMAX

Tags: modulation

Which modulation is used in WiMAX? And how does it work?
I found QAM-64 but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than one. thats for sure: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wimax/wimax_physical_layer.htm